# Flash - Detect tilting iOS

Tags: ios, flash, tilt

I've got a sample game here, and I wanted to give it a try on the iPad.

How do I listen for tilting in flash?

If I have a standard space invaders game, I want to move the spaceship left and right when I'm tilting the device left and right. How do I do this?

Thanks! =)

Comment: It's not? I'm just wondering how to listen for accelerometer changes. Thought there might already be presets for left and right tilt.. I'll digg some deeper then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [`AccelerometerEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/AccelerometerEvent.html)? Here's a tutorial and sample application using accelerometer to control the ball movements: http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=116

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out :) Probably spot on what I was looking for